# I want to change position of content in middle column

Tags: html, css

I have a website and want to put this in it but it dosn't work as i want. When i shrink window it looks like this -

[image: current code output when screen shrink to 767px]

I have used bootstrap in this. I have tried to solve swapping content of middle column but it dosen't work.

I want to swap content position of middle column when i shrink screen to 767px.

I want it look like this after shrink -

[image: actual output when i shrink window]

Please help me solve this out.

Thank you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="web-info-col">
        <div class="col-sm-12 column">
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
                        <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/cxBQn2h-I7umlBzFyIQ1IYSsZWC1SIdp6-cQxHuPX-QelGD8jMR5YgXuZlPnHz9ZHC4yQ6DKOQFUt6ouZc8fDg=s50" />
                        <h3 class="title">Discovery Strategy</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
                        <p>Get honest app reviews from the developer community.  Set the daily reviews per app and get a <strong>consistent</strong> flow of reviews.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 column">
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
                        <p>5% of developers don't have a single review for any of their apps.  Get <strong>unlimited</strong> reviews using our karma economy.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
                        <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />
                        <h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 column">
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
                        <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/X64zT-rJH6WzBLK5etDoqIKw98FiSWK0r_qL4JtXn8Z0Jq_wX4kl2A3ItdUlkl4-AM5znsfDlamhgrw8xaM0=s50" />
                        <h3 class="title">App Masterminds</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
                        <p>Collaborate with other developers, share knowledge and techniques on producing more <strong>profitable</strong> apps.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and css is

```
#web-info-col .col-sm-12{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    }
    #web-info-col .web-info-title{
            background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    #web-info-col .web-info-content{
            background: #fafafa;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:767px){
            #web-info-col .column{
                    display: block;
            }
            #web-info-col div.col-sm-12 .web-info-content{
                    padding: 20px;
            }
            #web-info-col div.web-info-title{
                    box-shadow: none;
                    padding: 20px;
                    box-shadow: 0px 11px 7px -6px #ccc;
            }
            #web-info-col .column:nth-child(2) .web-info-title{
                    background: #fafafa;
                    z-index: 0;
                    box-shadow: none;
            }
            #web-info-col .column:nth-child(2) .web-info-content{
                    background: #f2f2f2;
                    z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0px 11px 7px -6px #ccc;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add title after content.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
 <p>5% of developers don't have a single review for any of their apps. Get <strong>unlimited</strong> reviews using our karma economy.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
 <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />
 <h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>
 </div>
```

Reverse the two parts of code and everything will be ok. 
Then, remember to use bootstrap columns to do responsive behaviour.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: You want to swap only in responsive?

Comment: The other answerer has already posted something like this. Read the question carefully before you answer.

Comment: I'm not sure he want to swap the content only after window resize. In this case, so, you can handle the problem by creating the two behaviours and, then, use display none or display block according to what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the below at the html header to swap content at a width of 767px.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
    {
    var wsize = $( window ).width();
    if(wsize <=767)
    {
    $("div.swappable").html('<div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">'
                           +'<img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />'
                           +'<h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>'
                           +'</div>'    
                           +'<div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">'
                           +'<p>5% of developers don\'t have so and so.. </p>'
                           +'</div>'
                         '); 

    }
    });
<script>
```

And add a selector class `swappable` to the parent division like below:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 column swappable">
        <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
            <p>5% of developers don't have a single review for any of their apps.  Get <strong>unlimited</strong> reviews using our karma economy.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
            <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />
            <h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Important:**

Note that all the `single quotes` in the replacement pattern should be escaped as in `5% of developers don\'t` else these would break the script.

**Note:**
You might not include the `jquery.min.js` if it is already included.

Answer (score -1):

Just reverse the order of the 2 sections in the html.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 column">
 <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
 <p>5% of developers don't have a single review for any of their apps. Get <strong>unlimited</strong> reviews using our karma economy.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
 <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />
 <h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>
 </div>
 </div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-12 column">
 <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-title">
 <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/Bh6KdE6KntFGaLe6jdANbd2UmI7KADT67NjhPifO1ogZNktqr_X1Si_xQFNKO0k_Y7dEpx2bnr-7M0_5EsSRfg=s50" />
 <h3 class="title">Unlimited Reviews</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 web-info-content">
 <p>5% of developers don't have a single review for any of their apps. Get <strong>unlimited</strong> reviews using our karma economy.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wishes to do as he `want to swap content position of middle column when i shrink screen to 767px.`

Comment: swap only when window size is 767px. Not by changing code from starting